# ArcGIS Desktop in VMWare not connecting to USB?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-hosting, vmware

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 in a VMWare environment (university provided) with VMWare set to open USB when inserted.  I have inserted my thumb drive and have successfully worked within the folders, but upon trying to begin my mapping, data will not add.  I tried to set the path to the folder in ArcCatalog, but I receive a message saying the path is an "invalid or non-existent directory" despite being able to see these pathways in the connecting window.

I've connected and opened the files in the VMWare, it seems that this is an ArcGIS problem, not something about my VMWare settings nor the host computer settings, which, by the way, is a mac.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Do you mean that you get this message when you try to [Connect to Folder](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/map/working-with-arcmap/using-folder-connections.htm)? Please [edit] your question to specify.

Comment: If you right click on the folders and click properties does it say blocked ? you could also run ArcGIS as admin in case that helps.